# Android convert to Mp3

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to convert audio files created using MediaRecorder class in Android 2.1.

After 10 days searching on the net, I've only found FFMPEG solution, but frankly speaking, I don't know where to start.

I would like to compile the FFMPEG for Android on my Windows 7 64bit and use it into my java project.  Can someone link me to the right way?

Comment: Could you describe more your task? What do you want to convert and from what format to what?

Comment: Hi Mike, I want to convert MediaRecorder output(mp4 or 3gp) to mp3.

Comment: Sign is removed, Please refer the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 0):

To convert pcm to mp3, you can use this project:
http://code.google.com/p/freemp3fordroid

I think 'virual recorder' uses it too

Comment: for PCM(WAV) format, already I have solution, but the main problem is that the recording in WAV require large space on sdcard, so if the user do not have space, the job fail. This is why I am looking to convert the small Mediarecorder output (mp4 or 3gp) to Mp3.